# Have been trying to connect to the database using procedural php but i get error array to string conversion

Tags: php

```
<?php
function connect()
{
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test' ) or
    die ('There is a problem connecting to     the    db.');
return $conn;
}
function select_Db($conn){
   $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,UserName,Password FROM users') or
       die('Problem with query.');
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($id,$UserName,$Password);
   $rows = array();
   while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) 
       {
     $item = array(
       "id"=> $id, 
       "UserName"=>$UserName, 
       "Password" =>$Password  
     );  
     $rows[] = $item;
   }
   return $rows;
}
```

Have been trying to connect to the database using procedural php but i get error array to string conversion. Below is the code and respective errors. Please help to trace error in the code.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\MYSQL_Project\index.php.php on line 15
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\MYSQL_Project\index.php.php on line 16
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\MYSQL_Project\index.php.php on line 17
```

Comment: Bind, then execute; not the other way around.

Comment: @Fred-ii- results are bound after execute, check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: @FuzzyTree The docs don't lie then. However, I've seen so many times that it was used the other way around. No argument here ;-) Got mixed up with `bind_param`

Comment: Have tried to first bind still same error is being displayed.

Comment: Your error is not reproducible

Comment: Try the answer below then. Yet, how are you using this? There's no sign of any assigned variables for `($id,$UserName,$Password)` - If you're using it just as is, would most likely explain the error.

Comment: This one's dead in the water. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a `SELECT` try doing a regular `query()`. There's no need to over complicate this using prepared statements

```
$res = $conn->query('SELECT id,UserName,Password FROM users');
$rows = array();
while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) $rows[] = $row;
```

Comment: Fred, I thought the assignment is being done in the item array. The variables too are getting data from the database. Anyway bro, don't be cross with me I am really an armature at this.

Comment: @Goatman Your comment belongs up under your question. Don't worry, I'm not cross with you. I'm just trying to help solve this ASAP. ;-)

Comment: @Goatman We need to know exactly how you're using your code, if it's from a class, or passing variables from another source, if it's coming from a form. It's hard to say exactly, because from what I can see in your posted code, there's nothing assigned to your variables. I.e.: if coming from a form using POST as the method: `$UserName=$_POST['username'];` etc.

Comment: The idea I have is to connect to the database called test, select values from the users table and display the result in the index.php page like so <?php
include('mySql_Db.php');
$conn = connect();
$results = select_Db($conn);
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        foreach ($results as $rows) :?>
        <h2> <?php echo ['id'];?> </h2>
        <p> <?php  echo ['UserName']; ?> </p>   
        <p> <?php  echo ['Password'];?> </p>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: You need to do something like `<?php echo $rows['id'];?>` then, if you're going to use a `foreach` like that. @Goatman Yet, most likely needs to be inside the loop.